# Is it possible to graft plants from different families?

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy

For example, I have some Eastern Hemlock rootstock (Pinaceae), and want to graft a scion from Dawn Redwood (Cupressaceae) onto it. Is this possible? Is anything like this possible?

Comment: Not knowledgeable in this area, but I note the Dawn Redwood is deciduous and the Hemlock, like most conifers, is not.  Since deciduous plants commonly store reserves over the winter in their roots, an evergreen rootstock may not be compatible with a Dawn Redwood scion.

Comment: It makes me think of a french artisan who sells trees with 20-40 individual heirloom grafts on a single tree, which all flower and fruit throughout the summer. all apples, apricots, compatible trees. i found fig on mulberry, both moracea family.

Answer (score 3):

No. Exceptions are always possible, but it would be a noteworthy.

I just find this notes in: https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/hort494/mg/specific.grafting/compatibility.html

> Interfamilial
>
> Although there are a few reports of short-term graft union formation between distantly related (interfamilial) herbaceous species, there are no confirmed reports of interfamilial grafts between woody perennials.
>
> One extremely curious report of natural interfamilial graft compatibility which must be considered unconfirmed, and even unlikely, was the observation of La Rue (1934) [...]